# Most frequently occurring values in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

How can you select the most frequently occurring values in a MySQL database? Assuming I have a `num` field, with these rows:

`1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 17, 12, 1, 3, 17, 3`

If I wanted to find the three most frequently occurring values, 1, 3, and 17, how would I go about doing this (and getting a count)?

Would the proper method be to `SELECT UNIQUE` and do a tally for each individual value? Is there a more efficient method? This seems like it'd fail for larger data sets.

Thanks for the help! This is in PHP, with a MySQL database.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT num, COUNT(num) AS ct
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY num
ORDER BY ct DESC
```

This tells MySQL to group the results by the `num` column. By also also selecting `COUNT(num)` as the number of rows found for each `num` value, we can then issue the `ORDER BY` which will order the results according to how many rows each value of `num` has.

With these values in the table:

```
1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 17, 12, 1, 3, 17, 3
```

The results would be:

```
   num  | ct
============
     1  |  5
     3  |  3
    17  |  2
    12  |  1
```

Comment: So what would my result be with that query given my data set?

Comment: And standard `LIMIT` syntax could cut it off at x values? I +1'd by the way

Comment: You can add ``LIMIT X`` to the end, although ``LIMIT`` might come before the ``ORDER BY`` (I don't remember and don't have a MySQL instance in front of me at the moment) so you might have to do it in a subquery like ``SELECT * FROM (...query above...) LIMIT X``

Comment: `ct` is an alias. It lets you change the name of a field as it's viewed from the software end. Rather than having to look for a field named `COUNT(num)` in any array PHP creates from the query, you can force the field to be named via the alias, which'd be `ct` in this case.

Comment: I love the internet. That was an infinitely easier solution than what I had planned. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Cookbook has a section on [generating frequency distributions](http://www.freeopenbook.com/mysqlcookbook/mysqlckbk-CHP-13-SECT-4.html), which basically comes down to something like

```
SELECT num, COUNT(num) AS occurrence
FROM table
GROUP BY num
```